# I need to add a sentinel-2 image into Google Earth Engine Explorer with a specific ID

Tags: ndvi, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-explorer

I'm new at Google Earth Engine and Javascript.

I am using the graphical user interface of Google Earth Engine (Explorer) to obtain NDVI using sentinel 2. My study site is somewhere in Peru with an id:

`S2A_MSIL1C_20180110T150701_N0206_R039_T18KYG_20180110T162736.SAFE`

However, the format required is:

`COPERNICUS/S2/20151128T002653_20151128T102149_T56MNN`

and so I attempted to truncate my id using this code:

```
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180110T150701_20180110T162736_T18KYG');
```

But I get in response: Image.load:

`Image asset 'COPERNICUS/S2/20180110T150701_20180110T162736_T18KYG' not found.`

My complete code is:

```js
//  image

var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180110T150701_20180110T162736_T18KYG');


// Visualization parameters 

var visParams = {bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'], max: 3048, gamma: 1};
var visParams_ndvi = {min: -0.2, max: 0.8, palette: 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400,' +
    '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301'};

// Calculate NDVI

var image_ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);


// Map results

Map.centerObject(image,9)
Map.addLayer(image,visParams,'Sentinel-2 False Color Infrared')
Map.addLayer(image_ndvi,visParams_ndvi,'Sentinel-2 NDVI')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID is different, is `COPERNICUS/S2/20180110T150701_20180110T150702_T18KYG`. But, how to get it? Filter with date and tile. Check:

```js
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");

var image = ee.Image(imageCollection.filterDate('2018-01-10','2018-01-11').filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE','equals','18KYG').first());

print(image);
```

Result:

> Image COPERNICUS/S2/20180110T150701_20180110T150702_T18KYG (16 bands)
>
> type: Image id: COPERNICUS/S2/20180110T150701_20180110T150702_T18KYG
>
> version: 1515717142204526 bands: List (16 elements) properties: Object
>
> (62 properties)

Link to full code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fbebf04d399497c5d3456a7f7981011b

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, I need to make an edge detector using that satellite image in the google earth engine interface. I'm not familiar with the javascript language to perform that image treatment.

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_edges and http://schernthanner.de/playing-around-with-the-google-earth-engine-canny-edge-detection-in-the-cloud-on-berlins-most-recent-cloudless-sentinel-2-scene-realised-just-within-a-few-minutes

Comment: I need to obtain only this portion of the image that delimits by a polygon that has coordinates:

ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-72.2165, -16.2989], [-72.2146, -16.3010], [-72.2136, -16.2999], 
[-72.2156, -16.2980], [-72.2156, -16.2980]]])

I tried to put it in my code in this way:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4d4eaf8e0879d816d49d823e14eec278

but I do not get only that portion of the image but the whole map. What is my mistake?

Comment: FilterBounds is used to select images who intersect with this boundaries. Use updateMask for your task